# Proof by Induction (discrete series)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let P(n) denote the statement that n^p = n + kp
Base case - P(n) is true for n=1
Inductive step - Assume P(n) is true
               - Show that P(n+1) is true

Show that (n+1)^p = (n+1) + cp
                  = RHS of P(n) + (c-k)p + 1
                  = LHS of P(n) + (c-k)p + 1
                  = n^p + (c-k)p + 1

I can't close the gap between that last step and the LHS of P(n+1), i.e. (n+1)^p

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Using Binomial Expansion,

$$(m+1)^p-(m+1)-\{m^p-m\}=\sum_{1\le r\le p-1}\binom prm^{p-r}$$

Now, prove that $p$ divides $\binom pr$ for $1\le r\le p-1$

$\implies (m+1)^p-(m+1)- (m^p-m)$ is divisible by $p$

But by inductive hypothesis, $m^p-m$ is divisible by $p$

Comment: can you extend this hint one step further please?

Comment: @JacobCruise, I excluded the base case i.e., $n=1$. What's your confusion?

Comment: I don't see how (m^p - m) being divisible by p (your last step) completes the proof

Comment: @JacobCruise, if $p$ divides $a-b$ and $b,p$ must $a-b+b=a$

Comment: right, but wouldn't you be assuming that (m+1)^p = (m+1) is divisble by p?

Comment: @JacobCruise, no. If $T(m)=m^p-m, T(m+1)=(m+1)^p-(m+1)$ Now, I assume $T(m)$ is divisible by $p$ and show that $p$ divides $T(m+1)-T(m)$

Comment: Ok.. but I still don't see where you show that p divides T(m+1) - T(m). Sorry if I'm missing something...

Comment: @JacobCruise, do you see each of $\binom prm^{p-r}$ is divisible by $p?$

Comment: ahhh ok, i see that now. thanks for all of your help!